# Using a asterisk in an item identity without expanding it

Tags: msbuild

I'm trying to use MSBuild items to list the number of wildcard paths that can be evaluated in relation to a as-yet-unknown base path. As such, I'd like to be able to write:

```
<Item Include="Content\**\*.js" />
```

But *not* evaluate that as a path, but instead add it as a simple item whose `%(Identity)` is still the string "Content\**\*.js".

Is this possible in MSBuild?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have discovered, the item identity needs to be escaped. MSbuild has intrinsic functions to do this easily so you don't need to look up every character:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <Item Include="$([MSBuild]::Escape('Content\**\*'))" />
</ItemGroup>
```

Answer (score 1):

As is often the case, I discovered the answer immediately after posting.

As per [MSBuild Special Characters](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-special-characters), I need to escape the asterisk as `%2A`